# Is it possible to export a high res image from a Silverlight deepzoom site?

Tags: silverlight, photoshop

I'd like to download either the entire image, or at least a big part of it from here
http://www.xrez.com/yose_proj/yose_deepzoom/index.html
right now I'm zooming in, taking screen shots and tiling back together in Photoshop which is taking forever. Is there an easier way?

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

i ended up wringing a glovepie script to move the mouse automatically, then just talk screen shots and use photoshops photomerge feature to put togethere. it works ok. here's the glovepie script

```
// script to press and drag mouse
if  (Key.Left) {
debug = "start"
      mouse.X -= .8
      mouse.LeftButton = true
      mouse.X += .8
      wait 1 seconds
      mouse.LeftButton = false
debug = "released"
}

if  (Key.Right) {
debug = "start"
      mouse.X += .8
      mouse.LeftButton = true
      mouse.X -= .8
      wait 1 seconds
      mouse.LeftButton = false
debug = "released"
}

if  (Key.Up) {
debug = "start with the mouse near the bottom of the screen"
      mouse.Y -= .8
      mouse.LeftButton = true
      mouse.Y += .8
      wait 1 seconds
      mouse.LeftButton = false
debug = "released"
}

if  (Key.Down) {
debug = "start with the mouse near the top of the screen"
      mouse.Y += .8
      mouse.LeftButton = true
      mouse.Y -= .8
      wait 1 seconds
      mouse.LeftButton = false
debug = "released"
}
```

download glovepie (geat tool) from here http://glovepie.org/glovepie_download.php
click on the "I already have 100% Green power, I'm ready to download GlovePIE" button. yep it sounds weird but it does work